# Ktor websockets authentication

Tags: kotlin, authentication, websocket, jwt, ktor

The problem is related to WebSocket auth using JWT.

I know how to create a regular API call using route (HTTP requests), authenticate it using JWT and is working fine.

The thing that is bothering me is how to use JWT when working with WebSockets? The authenticate will not work with JWT like with HTTP requests. I have researched how but hit a dead end.

The question is how do i authenticate WebSocket routes using JWT? Any pointers are appreciated or if i am missing the point how it works would you be kind to explain what I am understanding wrong.

Comment: I think your way of doing it is right.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that wrapping the WebSocket route in authenticate will actually require the token in the header. From there I can do the same as i do with route (get the data from the call which is made to establish the connection) and close the socket if the user is not authenticated. Will leave it here if anyone gets stuck with this.

```
routing {
    authenticate {
        webSocket("/ws") {
            val principal = call.principal<JWTPrincipal>()
            val email = principal?.payload?.getClaim("email")?.asString()
            val expiresAt = principal?.expiresAt?.time ?: System.currentTimeMillis()

            val users = userService.getAllUsers()

            val randNum = Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(0, 2)

            if (randNum % 2 == 0) {
                close(CloseReason(CloseReason.Codes.PROTOCOL_ERROR, "Please auth the user"))
            }

            incoming.consumeAsFlow()
                .mapNotNull {
                    (it as? Frame.Text)?.readText()?.let { data ->
                        Json.decodeFromString<User>(data)
                    }
                }.collect {
                    send(Frame.Text(userService.insertUser(it).toString()))
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show please authorization config ?